# Xamarin: Use the Notify method that has a UICompletion Handler is not available

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have this **static Source Analysis** warning in Xamarin Studio:

> API Usage Issue: Use the *Notify method that has a `UICompletion Handler completion` parameter, the `bool` will tell you if the operation finished

when invoking `UIView.Animate(double duration, Action animation, Action completion)`:

```
UIView.Animate(duration,
   () => Animation(),
   () => Completion());
```

However, I can't seem to be able to pass parameters to the lambda expression. None of these options compile:

- `(bool) => Completion()`
- `(finished) => Completion()`
- `(bool finished) => Completion()`

How can I pass this `finished` parameter to to completion block?

Comment: Judging from the Xamarin comment on the method, and having never used it before myself, it sounds like when the `completion` `Action` fires, that means it has completed. Would not make sense for the `completion` `Action` to fire before the method has completed... right?

Comment: The question, which you actually answered, was about the `finished` parameter. The `Completion` fires whether the animation was completed or aborted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Animate` static methods use `NSAction` methods, more of a C# style annotation and `AnimateNotify` use `UICompletionHandler` methods, ObjC-style...

The `Animate` methods are just **helper** wrappers around `AnimateNotify`:

So instead of:

```
UIView.Animate(30, () => { }, () => { });
```

You can use:

```
UIView.AnimateNotify(30, () => { }, (bool finished) => { });
```

The result is the same....

Ref: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/fc55e4306f79491fd269ca2495c6a859799cb1c6/src/UIKit/UIView.cs#L121

Comment: Plus 1 - Pretty much what I wrote but in a much more confident sounding tone, with links! ;)

Comment: @hvaughan3 Iol... I think the key thing for me is that fact that `Animate` are just wrappers over the `AnimateNotify` methods...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you might be able to use one of the `AnimateNotify` or `AnimateNotifyAsync` method overloads as that passes back `UICompletionHandler` with a `bool`:

```
UIView.AnimateNotify(10, () => { }, finished => { });
```

OR

```
await UIView.AnimateNotifyAsync(10, () => { }, finished => { });
```

Comment: Ha! That is what the `*Notify` in the message meant. Thanks for clarifying.